# Term for matrix trace off main diagonal

Tags: matrices, terminology

The sum of a main diagonal of a matrix is called a trace. There are many other diagonals of a matrix, parallel to the main one. We can sum over these as well, to give "traces". But the term "trace" only seems to apply to the main diagonal. What is the ( or a good ) term to use for these sums of matrix diagonals, not limited only to the main diagonal?

Comment: Those other "diagonals" are sometimes called "broken diagonals", so I suppose you could invent the phrase, "broken trace".

Comment: One thing to be aware of (maybe you are) is that these off diagonal traces are not invariant under change of basis. (Take a well chosen diagonalizable matrix.)